# "Transaction does not match connection" when customize linq2sql logging

Tags: linq-to-sql, logging

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/karthik/archive/2008/05/19/custom-logging-in-linq-to-sql.aspx#10033705

I follow the above article to implement the custom logging, but when come to **SubmitChanges**, it throw a "Transaction does not match connection" exception, why's that??

EDIT: Maybe i should also override the DbTransaction?? I'm totally puzzled now

Comment: The code in that link looks very dodgy... (and some one has the same issue, see the comments).

Comment: @leppie notice the comment uhhhh..  It's really hard to customize the ling2sql log

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in inherit from the abstract class DbConnection, not the interface IDbConnection:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/e27cefc5-66d9-4ee0-8f44-6d9ff81c5e1f